# Markup error: document.getElementById(...) is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I am working on a Script for sorting boxes.
Here my problem. 
In the code:

```
Size_XS     = document.getElementById('Size_XS'+i).value*1;
```

seems to work without any problem.

While this one:

```
document.getElementById('Size_XS'+i).value = Size_XS;
```

will give me the error message: document.getElementById(...) is null or not an object.
if I change to:

```
document.getElementById('Size_XS1').value = Size_XS;
```

It all works, but then I cannot loop the file later and why does it work with i above?

My script below:

```
function calcbox(){
var count       = document.getElementById('count').value*1;

count           = count+1;

var box_num     = 0;

var header      = "<table style='border:#000 1px solid; background-color:#fff;'><tr><td width='25'><b>Box</b></td><td width='200'><b>Item name</b></td><td width='100'><b>Sizes</b></td><td width='250'><b>Pcs</b></td></tr>";

var output      = header+document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;
var total_qty;
var box_qty;
var item_name;

var Size_XS=0;
var Size_S=0;
var Size_M=0;
var Size_L=0;

/*for(var i=1;i<count;i++){*/


var i=1;
total_qty   = document.getElementById('total_qty'+i).value*1;
box_qty     = document.getElementById('box_qty'+i).value*1;
item_name   = document.getElementById('item_name'+i).value;

Size_XS     = document.getElementById('Size_XS'+i).value*1;
Size_S      = document.getElementById('Size_S'+i).value*1;
Size_M      = document.getElementById('Size_M'+i).value*1;
Size_L      = document.getElementById('Size_L'+i).value*1;

//Packing whole boxes
if(Size_XS>=box_qty){
    var Box_count = parseInt(Size_XS/box_qty);

    for(var i=1;i<=Box_count;i++){
        box_num = box_num+1;
        output = output+"<tr><td>"+box_num+"</td><td>"+item_name+"</td><td>S</td><td>"+box_qty+"</td></tr>";    
    }
    Size_XS = Size_XS-(box_qty*Box_count);
    alert(Size_XS);
    document.getElementById('Size_XS'+i).value = Size_XS;   
}
if(Size_S>=box_qty){
    var Box_count = parseInt(Size_S/box_qty);

    for(var i=1;i<=Box_count;i++){
        box_num = box_num+1;
        output = output+"<tr><td>"+box_num+"</td><td>"+item_name+"</td><td>S</td><td>"+box_qty+"</td></tr>";        
    }   
    Size_S = Size_S-(box_qty*Box_count);
    document.getElementById('Size_S'+i).value = Size_S; 
}
if(Size_M>=box_qty){
    var Box_count = parseInt(Size_M/box_qty);

    for(var i=1;i<=Box_count;i++){
        box_num = box_num+1;
        output = output+"<tr><td>"+box_num+"</td><td>"+item_name+"</td><td>M</td><td>"+box_qty+"</td></tr>";
    }
    Size_M = Size_M-(box_qty*Box_count);
    document.getElementById('Size_M'+i).value = Size_M; 
}   
if(Size_L>=box_qty){
    var Box_count = parseInt(Size_L/box_qty);

    for(var i=1;i<=Box_count;i++){
        box_num = box_num+1;
        output = output+"<tr><td>"+box_num+"</td><td>"+item_name+"      </td><td>L</td><td>"+box_qty+"</td></tr>";
    }       
        Size_L = Size_L-(box_qty*Box_count);
        document.getElementById('Size_L'+i).value = Size_L; 
    }
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output+"</table>";
document.getElementById("qty_boxes").value = box_num;

show('Volume_weight');
}
```

I'm getting my values from here in the HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="10">1</td>
<td width="120"><input id="item_name1" type="text" style="width:100px;" /></td>
<td width="80"><input id="box_qty1" type="text" style="width:30px;" /></td>
<td width="40"><input id="Size_XS1" type="text" style="width:30px;" onchange="totcalc(1);" /></td>
<td width="40"><input id="Size_S1" type="text" style="width:30px;" onchange="totcalc(1);" /></td>
<td width="40"><input id="Size_M1" type="text" style="width:30px;" onchange="totcalc(1);" /></td>
<td width="40"><input id="Size_L1" type="text" style="width:30px;" onchange="totcalc(1);" /></td>
<td width="60"><input id="total_qty1" type="text" style="width:50px;" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post your html markup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196) --- the element you are trying to access probably doesn't exist. For which value of `i` is the error thrown? I could imagine you want `i < Box_count`, not `i<=Box_count`.

Comment: I added a section of the HTML where I derive my variables from.

Comment: @FelixKling I placed the code after the element, but it's the same error.message. Also if I change to "Size_XS1" it all works. There must be some other reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `i` for two different things in the code. Firstly as a suffix to input element id values, and secondly as a loop counter for boxes. After `i` is no longer equal to 1 after various loops complete, the HTML element lookup by suffixed id fails:

```
document.getElementById('Size_XS'+i).value = Size_XS;
```

occurs after

```
for(var i=1;i<=Box_count;i++){ // ...
```

Feel free to delete the question if this is the problem :D

Comment: Thank you. This is it. I just replaced the first i and it's working. Thanks a lot!